# Finding the equation of a parabola using two tangents intersecting at a point

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, conic-sections, tangent-line

I am struggling with a question and need some help…

The question is the following:
[image: Figure 1]

There is a parabola which joins two tangents (L1 and L2) meeting at a point.

L1 has a slope of -1.8 and L2 a slope of 0.7.

P is given as $(0,0)$, and Q is given as $(30,y)$

I am trying to find the ‘a’ value for $ax^2 + bx + c$, as I have already found that $b=-1.8$ and $c=0$.

Where can I go from here to solve for the a value of the parabola?

Thanks! Much appreciated.
(Also this is my first time posting here, so forgive me if I am incorrectly formatting this question)

Comment: You can learn how to format your question with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: ** Updated formatting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have already set the derivative $f'(x) = 2ax + b$ to $-1.8$ at $x = 0$. Now you just need to use the fact that $f'(30) = 0.7$, as the gradient of the tangent at $x = 30$ is $0.7$.

Doing this you should get $60a - 1.8 = 0.7$ or $a = \frac{5}{120}$.

Comment: Ahhh!! So friggin stupid of me!! Thanks so much

Comment: That's okay: no worries!